# Using Variables From Other Functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Hopefully my code and question(s) are clear for understanding. If they are not please provide feed back.

I am fairly new to programing/coding so I decided to develop a program using Python that acts like a pizza ordering system. I eventually would like to use this code to develop a website using Django or Flask.

I have just finished the first step of this program where I am asking the user if this will be for delivery of pickup. Depending on what the user chooses the program will ask for specific information.

The area I feel like I am struggling with the most is developing classes and functions. specifically taking a variables from one function and using that variable in another function. I posted a past example of my code and I was advised that Global variables are not good to use in code. So I am trying really hard to refrain from using them.

Here is the code for reference:

```
import re 

running = True

class PizzaOrderingSys():
"""order a customized pizza for take out or delivery """

    def delivery_or_pickup(self): # Is the order for devilery or pickup?
        print("\nWill this order be for pickup or delivery?")
        self.delivery = input("P - pick up / D - delivery : ")
        self.delivery = self.delivery.title()

        if self.delivery == "D":
            while running == True:
                customerName = input("\nName for the order: ")
                if not re.match("^[a-zA-Z ]*$", customerName):
                    print("Please use letters only")
                elif len(customerName) == 0:
                    print("Please enter a vaild input")
                else: 
                    customerName = customerName.title()
                    break

            while running == True:
                customerPhoneNumber = input("\nEnter a phone number we can contact you at: ")
                if not re.match("^[0-9 ]*$", customerPhoneNumber): 
                    print("Please use numbers only")
                elif len(customerPhoneNumber) == 0: 
                    print("Please enter a a contact phone number")
                else: 
                    break 

            while running == True: 
                house_num = input("\nWhat is your house or unit number: ")
                if not re.match("^[0-9 /]*$", house_num):
                    print("Please use numbers only")
                elif len(house_num) == 0:
                    print("Please enter a valid input ")
                else: 
                    break

            while running == True:
                streetName = input("\nStreet name: ")
                if not re.match("^[a-zA-Z ]*$", streetName): 
                    print('Please use letters only.')
                elif len(streetName) == 0: 
                    print("Please enter a valid input")
                else:
                    streetName = streetName.title()
                    break

            while running == True: 
                city = input("\nCity: ")
                if not re.match("^[a-zA-Z ]*$", city): 
                    print("Please use letters only")
                elif len(city) == 0: 
                    print("Please enter a valid input")
                else:
                    city = city.title()
                    break

            while running == True:
                zip_code = input("\nZip Code:")
                if not re.match("^[0-9 /]*$", zip_code): 
                    print("Please use numbers only")
                elif len(zip_code) == 0 or len(zip_code) > 5: 
                    print("Please enter a valid input")
                else:
                    break 

        elif self.delivery == "P":
            while running == True:
                customerName = input("\nName for the order: ")
                if not re.match("^[a-zA-Z ]*$", customerName): 
                    print("Please use letters only")
                elif len(customerName) == 0: 
                    print("Please enter a valid input")
                else: 
                    customerName = customerName.title()
                    break
                
            while running == True:
                customerPhoneNumber = input("\nEnter a phone number we can contact you at: ")
                if not re.match("^[0-9 ]*$", customerPhoneNumber): 
                    print("Please use numbers only")
                elif len(customerPhoneNumber) == 0:  
                    print("Please enter a valid input")
                else:
                    break 
        else:
            print("Please enter P or D ")
            delivery_or_pickup() 

order = PizzaOrderingSys()
order.delivery_or_pickup()
```

**My question is this: How would I use variables found in one function of my class and use it in another future function??**

For example if I wanted to retrieve variables the functions customerName, customerPhoneNumber, house_num, streetName, city, Zip_code found in delivery_or_pick() function and use them in a function called:

```
def customer_receipt():
```

**What would I need to do to my exiting code or to the `def customer_receipt()` function to obtain that information?**

Any help with my questions or advise on any other area that stick out to you would be be greatly appropriated.
This is my second post on Stackoverflow so I apologize if what i am asking is unclear or the format of my question might is off, I am still learning.
Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here is that you can use your class variables to save data between method calls. Methods are functions that belong to a class. For example you could use Python's class initialization and create a dict of orders. Here is a simple example of such system, take a note of the usage of `self` keyword. `self` refers to the instance of the class and you can use it to access the variables or methods of the instance:

```
class PizzaOrderingSys:
    def __init__(self):
        # Initializing some class variables
        self.running = True # Now you can use self.running instead of global running variable
        self.orders = {}

    def delivery_or_pickup(self):
        # Somewhere at the end where you have collected the needed info
        order = {
            "zip_code": zip_code,
            "city": city,
            # You can enter all of the needed data similarly
        }

        order_id = "SomeIdHere" # ID could be anything, it just should be unique
        self.orders[order_id] = order 
        return order_id 
    
    def customer_receipt(self, id):
        # Now you can access all of the order here with self.orders

        order = self.orders.get(id) # Select some specific order with id.
                                    # Using get to avoid the situation
                                    # where no orders or invalid id would raise an exception
        if order:
            receipt = f"Order {id}:\nCustomer city {order['city']}"
        else:
            receipt = None
        return receipt

pizzasystem = PizzaOrderingSys()
order_id = pizzasystem.delivery_or_pickup()
receipt = pizzasystem.customer_receipt(order_id)
print(receipt) 
# >>> Order 1235613:
#     Customer city Atlantis
```

I recommend that you read more about classes, for example, python docs have great [material](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) about them.

Comment: You just did an extreme make over on my code and I appreciate the heck out of that. I have been look up resource on how to do this be I feel none or they are hard to understand because they don't really pertain to what I am trying to do. Or maybe im just having a hard time warping my head around it at the moment. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: @ChrisJaurigue You are on right track with the classes, because they are excellent for data encapsulation, mutation and state management. For the Flask and Django part, the situation is a bit different as they use different patterns such as MVC where you use  models and views to save and edit data. I left that part out from this minimalistic answer, as I think it is better to have good grasp of classes first, because they are fundamental part of Python, and you will still need them even with Django (Models for example are classes).